# DependONGroups annotation testng

Tags: java, maven, annotations, testng

I am using DependOnGroups parameter in @test annotation.the code looks like,

```
@Test(groups={"datacompare"},dependsOnGroups = {"AzkabanFlow"})
```

Now the requirement is we need to run the test only for the group datacompare which is done by specifying the maven parameter,

```
clean test site -DtestGroup=datacompare
```

Since the above group has dependency with the group azkban flow, i am getting the error

```
[ERROR] DependencyMap::Method "DataValidationTestSuite.data_Comparison(java.lang.reflect.Method)[pri:0, instance:com.kohls.test.automation.framework.testsuite.DataValidationTestSuite@1608e1a]" depends on nonexistent group "AzkabanFlow"
```

Can someone suggest me a way to run the test for datacompare without removing the parameter DependOnGroups and also not calling the particular group mentioned in dependOnGroup parameter in maven parameter for test run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change your `@Test` annotation to something like below

`@Test(groups={"datacompare"},dependsOnGroups = {"AzkabanFlow"}, ignoreMissingDependencies=true)`

This would cause TestNG to ignore missing dependencies and hopefully it should solve your problem as well.

Javadocs for the same can be referred [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-gc0bb558-111/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#ignoreMissingDependencies--).